# Do collateralized loans impact your credit score?

Tags: loans, credit-score, refinance

Do collateralized loans impact your credit score?
Such as a securities loan collateralized by your stocks, a refinance on your home, a personal loan collateralized by a car, and so on.

Comment: A loan can only impact your credit score if the loan company reports everything to a credit bureau.  (Otherwise, how do they know about it?)  I'd expect a "securities loan collateralized by your stocks to **not** be reported, but your other examples **to* be reported.

Comment: For example, a mortgage is a collateralized loan, and it certainly impacts your CS.

Comment: Ah so it depends on if the loan company reports it or not, and not if the loan is secured or not. Thanks.

Comment: Credit scores work differently in different places. Where in the world are you? Please edit, comment or add an appropriate tag.